# mnesia_fatal, "Cannot open log file"

Tags: erlang, mnesia

I'm getting the following error when I try to put ~1000 records into one table. I've put >1000 records in a table before. There's plenty of space on the disk. Any ideas what would cause this write to fail? It usually fails trying to write PREVIOUS.LOG, but I have also seen it fail writing to one of the table's .DCL files.

```
Got event: {mnesia_system_event,
           {mnesia_fatal,"Cannot open log file ~p: ~p~n",
               ["/opt/notifier/rel/notifier/Mnesia.notifier@ql1erldev1/PREVIOUS.LOG",
                {file_error,
                    "/opt/notifier/rel/notifier/Mnesia.notifier@ql1erldev1/PREVIOUS.LOG",
                    emfile}],
```

Comment: `emfile` is a posix error meaning `too many open file`. Increase that `limit`.

Comment: Maybe you can read this link: http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-bugs/2015-May/004989.html

Comment: How may file descriptors does Mnesia typically need?

Comment: I just realized I have something else eating up my file descriptors. I'm testing socket connections and each one holds a descriptor. Somewhere around 1000 connections I run out of descriptors. Then it happens to be the Mnesia write that fails.